# Configure custom ObjectMapper for @RestController within Springboot

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I have two ObjectMappers configured within a springboot application. I declare these in a configuration class like the following:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public ObjectMapper getPrimary() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
  }


  @Bean
  public ObjectMapper getSecondary() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
  }

}
```

The @Primary ObjectMapper works without issue. I'm at a loss in understanding how to get a @RestController to use the secondary ObjectMapper though. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use qualifiers:

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {

  @Bean("myPrimaryOjectMapper")
  @Primary
  public ObjectMapper getPrimary() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
  }


  @Bean("mySecondaryOjectMapper")
  public ObjectMapper getSecondary() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
  }

}
```

and then when injecting:

```java
@Autowired
@Qualifier("mySecondaryOjectMapper")
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

You can read more for example here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation#qualifierVsPrimary

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I wasn't able to get it to work with the @RestController implicitly, but I ended up injecting the secondary ObjectMapper into the rest controller, and then directly using the mapper to parse the input.